# An object that includes an image uploaded using an input element. How can you convert the image inside that object into a URL format?

Tags: reactjs

In a React , I have an object that includes an image, that will be uploaded using an input element. How can I convert the image inside that object into a URL format that can be displayed on the page?

```
export const DisplayImage = () => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

    return (
        <>
            <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setImage(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))} />
            {image && <img src={image} alt="Uploaded Image" />}
        </>
    )
}
```

When using it in an object:

```js
const updateUserDetailHandler = (event) => {

        const { name, value, files } = event.target;

        if (name === 'userProfile') {
            setProfile(URL.createObjectURL(files[0]))

            setNewUser({
                ...newUser,
                [name]: profile
            })
        }
        else {
            setNewUser({
                ...newUser,
                [name]: value
            })
        }

        console.log(profile);

    }
```

When the image is being added in object, the pages goes blank. I need to solve it.